# Executar esta função partir de um botão

Tags: jquery

Como podem estar vendo no exemplo abaixo, quando os links são clicados uma div aparece e ao clicar o botão de *voltar* do navegador, ela se oculta. Gostaria que ao clicar no botão "fechar", dentro da página aberta, também possa ocultá-la. Preciso que seja reproduzido o mesmo sistema que acontece ao usar o *voltar* do navegador, porque com uma função simples de ocultar (`$('div').hide();`) acaba bugando esse sistema, quero dizer, para de funcionar a volta pelo botão do navegador. Podem me ajudar?

link no codepen: https://codepen.io/thiago-the-styleful/pen/BvoQRX

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#paginaUm").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina.um').fadeIn();
  });
  
  $("#paginaDois").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina.dois').fadeIn();
  });
  
});

window.onhashchange = function(e) {
  var oldURL = e.oldURL.split('#')[1];
  var newURL = e.newURL.split('#')[1];

  if (oldURL == 'paginaUm') {
    $('.pagina.um').fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
   if (oldURL == 'paginaDois') {
    $('.pagina.dois').fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  //console.log('old:'+oldURL+' new:'+newURL);
}
```

```css
  
  body {
    background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1000/1010);
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
  }

.pagina{position:fixed; display:none; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:gray; color:white; padding:20px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#paginaUm" id="paginaUm">Pagina 1</a>
  <div class="pagina um">
  <h1>Popup 1</h1>
  <button class="fechar">fechar.</button>
</div>

<a href="#paginaDois" id="paginaDois">Pagina 2</a>
  <div class="pagina dois">
  <h1>Popup 2</h1>
  <button class="fechar">fechar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar o método `window.history.back();` que vai disparar o mesmo evento `onhashchange`. Crie o event handler para o botão `.fechar`:

```
$(".fechar").click(function(event){
   window.history.back();
});
```

Como isso irá restaurar a URL na barra de endereços do navegador.

> Se você fizer um simples `$('.pagina').fadeOut();`, a hash no endereço do
>   navegador não mudará.

Vou colocar o exemplo para ilustrar, mas como aqui no sandbox não dá pra ver as mudanças de URL, vou colocá-las no `console.log`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
   $(".fechar").click(function(event){
      window.history.back();
   });
  
  $("#paginaUm").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina.um').fadeIn();
  });
  
  $("#paginaDois").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina.dois').fadeIn();
  });
  
});

window.onhashchange = function(e) {
  var oldURL = e.oldURL.split('#')[1];
  var newURL = e.newURL.split('#')[1];

  if (oldURL == 'paginaUm') {
    $('.pagina.um').fadeOut();
    console.log(location.href);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
   if (oldURL == 'paginaDois') {
    $('.pagina.dois').fadeOut();
    console.log(location.href);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  console.log(location.href);
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1000/1010);
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
  }

.pagina{position:fixed; display:none; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:gray; color:white; padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#paginaUm" id="paginaUm">Pagina 1</a>
  <div class="pagina um">
  <h1>Popup 1</h1>
  <button class="fechar">fechar.</button>
</div>

<a href="#paginaDois" id="paginaDois">Pagina 2</a>
  <div class="pagina dois">
  <h1>Popup 2</h1>
  <button class="fechar">fechar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: esse funcionou corretamente!! tentei o dos outros mas sempre apresentava algum bug nas outras funções. obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Você só precisa criar um evento no botão fecha, e como você esta usando a classe "pagina" no conteúdo que você quer fechar, então utilize o método "fadeOut" para dar o mesmo efeito de quando foi aberta.

```
$(".fechar").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina').fadeOut();
});
```

Veja o exemplo utilizando o seu código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#paginaUm").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina.um').fadeIn();
  });
  
  $("#paginaDois").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina.dois').fadeIn();
  });
  
  $(".fechar").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina').fadeOut();
  });
  
});

window.onhashchange = function(e) {
  var oldURL = e.oldURL.split('#')[1];
  var newURL = e.newURL.split('#')[1];

  if (oldURL == 'paginaUm') {
    $('.pagina.um').fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
   if (oldURL == 'paginaDois') {
    $('.pagina.dois').fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  //console.log('old:'+oldURL+' new:'+newURL);
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1000/1010);
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
  }

.pagina{position:fixed; display:none; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:gray; color:white; padding:20px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#paginaUm" id="paginaUm">Pagina 1</a>
  <div class="pagina um">
  <h1>Popup 1</h1>
  <button class="fechar">fechar.</button>
</div>

<a href="#paginaDois" id="paginaDois">Pagina 2</a>
  <div class="pagina dois">
  <h1>Popup 2</h1>
  <button class="fechar">fechar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado pela tua resposta!! funcionou como pedi, mas acabou bugando outras funçoes (não entendo MESMO o  porquê), mas a do colega abaixo deu certo usando o window.history.back